# Python selenium webdrive cannot upload file with "unknown command" exception

Tags: python, selenium, exception

I try to upload an image/file on Facebook Messager, whose sample URL is https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/471646182511990 (If you want to try, you need to open Facebook Messager on your Chrome browser and get a valid URL). But it failed with an "Unknow command" exception.

I search but cannot find any suitable answer. A thread "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63272928/selenium-webdriver-python-cant-upload-file-send-keys-is-throws-elementnotinte" is close but it is NOT the same problem.

Version:

1. Python 3.9
2. selenium: 4.1.0

Code:

```
def sendMedia(mediaFile):
    filePath="file.jpg")
    try:
        fileInputBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
    except
        return False
    fileInputBox.send_keys(filePath)
    sleep(randint(1,2))
    fileInputBox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    sleep(randint(5, 6))
    return True
```

Problem:  This line "fileInputBox.send_keys(filePath)" return the below error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Workspace\Property\Facebook\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 785, in _upload
raise e

File "D:\Workspace\Property\Facebook\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 776, in _upload
return self._execute(Command.UPLOAD_FILE, {'file': content})['value']

File "D:\Workspace\Property\Facebook\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 710, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)

File "D:\Workspace\Property\Facebook\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "D:\Workspace\Property\Facebook\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown command: unknown command: session/83896857b2899e4a7c53c4a8dca78976/se/file

Stacktrace:

Backtrace:

```
Ordinal0 [0x00C16903+2517251]

Ordinal0 [0x00BAF8E1+2095329]

Ordinal0 [0x00AB2848+1058888]

Ordinal0 [0x00AF429E+1327774]

Ordinal0 [0x00AF4089+1327241]

Ordinal0 [0x00A950AF+938159]

Ordinal0 [0x00A955C6+939462]

Ordinal0 [0x00A958F1+940273]

GetHandleVerifier [0x00DA5904+1577972]

GetHandleVerifier [0x00E50B97+2279047]

GetHandleVerifier [0x00CA6D09+534521]

GetHandleVerifier [0x00CA5DB9+530601]

Ordinal0 [0x00BB4FF9+2117625]

Ordinal0 [0x00A94E40+937536]

Ordinal0 [0x00A94848+936008]

GetHandleVerifier [0x00E78B5C+2442828]

BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7732FA29+25]

RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775C7A9E+286]

RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x775C7A6E+238]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Selenium 4.1.0 and Python 3.9.
I have made some workaround but I don't like it.

In selenium site-package in remote_connection.py file I have changed line 218 from:
`Command.UPLOAD_FILE: ('POST', "/session/$sessionId/se/file"),`
to:
`Command.UPLOAD_FILE: ('POST', "/session/$sessionId/file"),`

Now it is working but as I said it shouldn't be like that I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Mark's Answer is working for me.

In order to keep package code clean, I use a workaround as below:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Remote
from selenium.webdriver.remote import remote_connection
from selenium.webdriver.remote.command import Command

def do_something(url: str, session_id: str)

    rmt_con = remote_connection.RemoteConnection(url)
    rmt_con._commands.update({
        Command.UPLOAD_FILE: ("POST", "/session/$sessionId/file")
    })
    driver = Remote(command_executor=rmt_con, desired_capabilities={})
    driver.session_id = session_id
    
    # Do amazing things afterwards
    driver.get('')
```